# Text width adjusting

Tags: css, mobile

I have problem with text width on mobile devices on this [website](http://centrplastic.ru).

[image: Mobile Screen image]

I need to make text full width.

I try make div 100%, 1000px, insert text in table, make body min-width...

Answer (score 0):

do you want to justify text on the screen? 
You can use text-align CSS property to center.
like this

```
.center-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
.center-wrapper * {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

for below HTML:

```
<div class="center-wrapper">
  <div data-role="button">button text</div>
</div>
```

or set margins of the screen like:

```
.center-wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem has to do with wrong `viewport` declaration.
You should use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

instead of

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Because you want to make sure the viewport gets adjusted correctly according to the pixel ratio of every mobile device. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag for more detailed information about usage of `viewport`

Comment: @user3257103 OK I see it now online, you've added the correct meta viewport now. And now the font size isn't scaled down but is displayed correctly on mobile devices but the width of the page doesn't scale down to the device width. So all you have to do now is to make the whole CSS responsive, which means replacing specific `width` with `max-width` and so on. This is quite straightforward but you have to know responsive design. Would like to help more but it can be quite lengthy when you have lots of content.